# Procedure call function with table fields

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

How to call a function in a procedure with the table fields?

I've read the question [How to call a stored procedure using table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595971/), but it is different.

I have a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION valorPedido (qtde int, decimal value (11.2)) RETURNS double
BEGIN
 RETURN qtde * value;
END
```

I have the procedure ItemPedido:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ItemPedido (numped int, int codtab, codpro int (4), qtdped int, decimal valitem (11.2), decimal valped (11.2), datped date)
BEGIN
insert into itens_pedido (numped, codtab, codpro, qtdped, valitem, valped, datped) values ​​(numped, codtab, codpro, qtdped, valitem, valped, datped);
END
```

And a table called itens_Pedido:

```
IdItemPedido int (11) AI PK
NumPed int (11)
CodTab int (11)
CodPro int (4)
QtdPed int (11)
ValItem decimal (11.2)
ValPed decimal (11.2)
DatPed date
```

I want to call the procedure this way:

```
call ItemPedido (1, 99, 1, 10, 4, valorPedido (qtdped, valitem), sysdate());
```

*Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'qtdped' in 'field list'*

But I can only this:

```
call ItemPedido (1, 99, 1, 10, 4, valorPedido (10, 4), sysdate());
```

Comment: You should be careful with your notations.  You've written sequences similar to `decimal value(11.2)` in a couple of places, which should surely be `value decimal(11, 2)` — reordering the words and using commas instead of full stops.

Comment: valorPedido function does not know qtdped. you can pass a literal oy apply this on the table "IdItemPedido" from where it will pick value of qtdped.

Comment: As for the error, the problem is that there is no variable `qtdped` in the scope where you call `valorPedido()` in the argument list to the call to `ItemPedido()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this;

**Remove the valped param from sp and update the table after row insert using your function calculation.**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ItemPedido (numped int, int codtab, codpro int (4), qtdped int, decimal valitem (11.2),  datped date)
    BEGIN

    insert into itens_pedido (numped, codtab, codpro, qtdped, valitem, datped) 
values ​​(numped, codtab, codpro, qtdped, valitem, datped);

set @lastId=LAST_INSERT_ID();

    set @valped= (select valorPedido(qtdped,valitem) from  itens_pedido where AI =@lastId);

update itens_pedido set valped=@valped where AI=@lastId;

    END
```

Comment: I had to change the AI by IdItemPedido and it worked perfectly.
Thank you.