# How to call a Stored Procedure from a BI Publisher Report?

Tags: sql, plsql, bi-publisher

I have a stored procedure, I want to call it from a BI report. My purpose is just to execute the procedure. I don't want any display output in report. Just execution.

Comment: What version of BI publisher? EBS? Stand alone? Do you want it called just once? For specific records?

Comment: Version is : 11.1.1.7.160719. Its stand alone. I want to call it whenever required. And just want the report to execute this procedure when report is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some R & D, I have found the solution, just create a group in your BI report and add the code as

```
DECLARE
type refcursor is REF CURSOR;
xdo_cursor refcursor;
BEGIN
OPEN :xdo_cursor FOR
select 1 from dual;
<<Procedure name>>;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a procedure from a select statement. but you can use a function in a select statement, and you can call a procedure from a function.

Try creating a function that calls the procedure. Then use that function in one of your BI Publisher select statements.

This could provide some additional guidance:
[oracle call stored procedure inside select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865149/oracle-call-stored-procedure-inside-select)

You'll need to provide some output in the function. You can just have it be "success" or something simple hard coded, but make sure to pass an exception from the procedure to the function, and then from that back to the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your data definition you can call procedures in the before or after report trigger objects.

For example, this calls a program named `xref_burst_pkg.AfterReport()` in the after report trigger in an xml data definition.

```
<dataTrigger name="afterReport" source="xref_burst_pkg.AfterReport()"/>
```

Or in a 6i Oracle Report for example, you can add something like this in an after report trigger to call bursting program:

```
function AfterReport return boolean is
 req_id     number;
begin

req_id := FND_REQUEST.SUBMIT_REQUEST ('XDO',
'XDOBURSTREP',
'',
'',
FALSE,
'Y',
fnd_global.conc_request_id,
'Y',
chr(0),'', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
                                                                                
if req_id = 0 then
    srw.message(100,'Failed to submit bursting program');
end if;

SRW.USER_EXIT('FND SRWEXIT');
return (TRUE);
end;
```