# How to call stored procedure with clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I found this way also called be used.

I am able to call function with clause.

Code:

```
with FUNCTION ADD_NUM(a in number) 
return number 
as
begin
    return (a*a);
end;
        
select ADD_NUM(10) from dual;
```

It worked for me and got me output.

But now I want to know how to call procedure?

```
with 
    PROCEDURE ADD_NUM(a in number , result out number)
    as
    begin
         result := a*a;
    end;
    
variable v number;    
select ADD_NUM(10,v) from dual;
```

Comment: You can't call a stored procedure in a select statement. Can you explain more about what you are trying to solve? Depending on how much of an XY Problem this is, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2865149/2221001) may offer some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the procedure in SQL, but you can in PL/SQL. How? Create **both** function **and** procedure; then call procedure from function and - finally - return result:

```
SQL> with
  2  procedure p_add_num (a in number, result out number) as   --> procedure
  3    begin
  4      result := a * a;
  5    end;
  6  function f_add_num (a in number)                          --> function
  7    return number
  8  as
  9    result number;
 10  begin
 11    p_add_num(a, result);         --> call procedure from function
 12    return result;
 13  end;
 14  select f_add_num(10)            --> call function
 15  from dual;
 16  /

F_ADD_NUM(10)
-------------
          100

SQL>
```